# KMM on iOS: There is no event loop. Use runBlocking { ... } to start one

Tags: kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

I'm trying to use `coroutines` in a `Kotlin Multiplatform` project. I'm not experienced in either.

I'm trying to call this function

```
fun startFlow {
    coroutineScope.launch { 
        withContext(defaultDispatcher) {
           myFlow.collect { next -> onNext(next) }
        } 
    }
}
```

`coroutineScope` on `iOS` is this

```
val defaultScope: CoroutineScope = object : CoroutineScope {
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = SupervisorJob() + Dispatchers.Default
}
```

This is not the only call that gives me this problem, in fact all calls to `coroutines` seem to fail with this error:

```
kotlin.IllegalStateException: There is no event loop. Use runBlocking { ... } to start one.
```

This is how I import the library

```
val commonMain by getting {
        dependencies {
            implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.4.3")
        }
    }
```

I'm using `Kotlin` 1.4.31. This problem is only present in `iOS`, `Android` works flawlessly.

I don't understand if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

New native concurrency model [available](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2021/08/try-the-new-kotlin-native-memory-manager-development-preview/) for preview. Check out [New memory model migration guide](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/kotlin-native/NEW_MM.md). `native-mt` suffix described below will no longer be needed after the release of this functionality along with Kotlin **1.7.0**.

---

for iOS you need to use coroutines with suffix "native-mt", more info [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/mobile/concurrency-and-coroutines.html#multithreaded-coroutines)

so replace your import with

```
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.5.2-native-mt")
```

Also note, that as per [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/mobile/concurrency-and-coroutines.html#multithreaded-coroutines):

> When using other libraries that also depend on `kotlinx.coroutines`, such as Ktor, make sure to specify the multithreaded version of `kotlinx-coroutines`. You can do this with `strictly`:

```
implementation ("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.5.2-native-mt"){
    version {
        strictly("1.5.2-native-mt")
    }
}
```

Comment: On the GitHub repository of coroutines it says that if you have the generic dependency on the common source set, it will import the platform specific versions. I though the suffix wasn't needed

Comment: I have replaced a link with an official documentation one, it describes why do we still need to use it. Shortly - they're still working on it. Also there you'll find how to use strictly version in case when your other dependencies depends on coroutines

Comment: Uncaught Kotlin exception: kotlin.native.IncorrectDereferenceException: illegal attempt to access non-shared <object>@300b968 from other thread 

I'm getting this now after adding the strictly function.

Comment: @BoldijarPaul this is an other issue. Check out how Kotlin Native concurrency model works in [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-concurrency.html). Shortly, you can't use `var` in your shared code (without atomic wrappers), but you can also face issues when you need to call `froze` when creating new objects. The code in your question doesn't seems to be causing such exception. You can update your question with more details/stacktrace, as well as relevant code, in case you won't find the answer in documentation.

Answer (score 3):

If you're on the latest version of KMM, and the above native-mt library doesn't work for you, then here's a solution for you -

1. Go to your `gradle.properties`
2. In `#kotlin` section (or on a new line), add the following line

   `kotlin.native.binary.memoryModel=experimental`
3. Sync the gradle files

This should enable the experimental memory model for Kotlin and your project should start working on iOS.

Comment: As of Kotlin Version `1.7.20`, the new memory manager is enabled by default, see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-memory-manager.html.

Totally unrelated sidenote: that's why 'latest version' is not optimal, as no one knows which version was the 'latest' at the time of writing. So please be precise. No offense tho!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the regular `coroutines` library, but then you need to create a custom [CoroutineDispatcher](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutine-context-and-dispatchers.html) that posts the task on the [mainRunLoop](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsrunloop), e.g.:

```
object NSLooperDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher() {
    override fun dispatch(context: CoroutineContext, block: Runnable) {
        NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop.performBlock {
            block.run()
        }
    }
}

// use custom dispatcher
withContext(NSLooperDispatcher) {
    myFlow.collect { next -> onNext(next) }
}
```

There are problems with switching threads which the `native-mt` branch of coroutines is explicit about, so it may still be a good idea to use it. Otherwise, you are confined on one the main thread.